# Rails Content Security Policy not allowing external images from API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-security-policy

I am using an external API to display images from source `https://i.ibb.co`

The img src URL looks like this: `https://i.ibb.co/R0VHJbd/ds.png`

In production, I'm having an issue displaying the images. In the console, the error:

`Refused to load the image 'https://i.ibb.co/R0VHJbd/ds.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data:".`

However, even after setting my Content Security Policy in the index.html to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' https://i.ibb.co; connect-src 'self' https://api.imgbb.com; child-src *; object-src *">
```

I am still getting the error

I am also getting the same error when attempting to upload through the API, even though the `connect-src` is defined in my meta tag

`Refused to connect to 'https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?expiration=600&key=<key>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

I have `rack-cors` enabled to allow all requests

application.rb

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: :any
  end
end
```

config/initializers/rack_cors.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
    allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', 
        headers: %w(Authorization),
        expose: %w(Authorization),
        methods: :any
    end
end
```

config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb

```
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
  policy.default_src :self, :https
  policy.font_src    :self, :https, :data
  policy.img_src     :self, :https, "i.ibb.co", :data
  policy.object_src  :none
  policy.script_src  :self, :https
  policy.style_src   :self, :https
  # If you are using webpack-dev-server then specify webpack-dev-server host
  policy.connect_src :self, :https, "http://localhost:3035", "ws://localhost:3035" if Rails.env.development?

  # Specify URI for violation reports
  # policy.report_uri "/csp-violation-report-endpoint"
end
```

How can I resolve this?

Note: This is an Angular project running on the Rails server, so the Angular index.html that is served on the homepage is compiled first, followed by Rails

For reference: my [project on Heroku](http://annotate-software-api.herokuapp.com)